# selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, python-3.6

I'm programming for fun so I wanted to learn about selenium webdriver using twitter but I have a problem.

The problem comes when I try to put my text in the box of the tweet:
[image: Box to tweet]

So I have to kind of activate the element that's on the box and that went good:

```
TBot = webdriver.Chrome()
twitter_box_act = Tbot.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="public-DraftEditorPlaceholder-inner"]')
Tbot.execute_script("arguments[0].click(), twitter_box_act)
```

But once i try to put some text on the box this error appears:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

The code that I've used to try to put text on the box is the next:

```
    tweet_entry = self.bot.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@data-text="true"]')
    tweet_entry.send_keys("some text here")
```

So what I've tried is looking more deep in the code with **F12** this is what I got:
[image: before writing]
[image]

I tried to put some time.sleep(x) between every step that didn't solve it.

I tried editing first the **br tag** and after that editing the **span tag** but I still had the same message error

I've been looking on the internet with Twitter projects with selenium as well but since they change the UI is not the same HTML body.

Am I missing something?

**PS: I skipped the login part since that has nothing to do with the problem**

Answer (score 0):

You have tried change this line:
 -->Tbot.execute_script("arguments[0].click(), twitter_box_act)
The error is for interactable, and you has interable in arguments.

Comment: What's exactly the problem? I'm a beginner so maybe what is obvious for you it isn't that obvious for me, so could you explain it more detailed please? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for the delay, you has tried to acces a element in position 0, and you have a error in iteration. The element is not iterable, the element probabily is not an array, so don't have the possibyliti to iterability.Try this --
Copy the xpath of the element from the brownser and paste in the execute_script method, in the tab elements click and search for xpath, copy and paste.